# How to combine :hover with :not()?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm trying to create an hover effect for elements without the class 'is-current' but somehow the following SCSS does not work as expected:

```
.class {
    &:not(.is-current):hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
    &.is-current {
      color: #000;
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why the generated css is this:

```
class::active, class::focus, class::hover {
    background: #fff;
}
```

I already tried `&:not(".is-current")` but the result is the same.

Does somebody know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Posting sample code of minimal code to demonstrate/recreate the issue will get you an answer faster.

Comment: Works for me - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KKNMaGM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works pretty normal for me,

```
.some {
    &.is-current { color: blue }
    &:not(.is-current):hover { color: red }
}
```

and the output is

```css
.some.is-current {
    color: blue;
}

.some:not(.is-current):hover {
    color: red;
}
```

just like you expect, which works fine:

```css
.some.is-current { color: blue }
.some:not(.is-current):hover { color: red }
```

```html
<span class="some">One</span> · <span class="some is-current">One</span>
```

Perhaps there's something else to your problem.

Comment: This was an issue with very strange SASS configuration. Thanks for verifying!